# Quick way to change method signature for all methods by adding a parameter in eclipse

Tags: eclipse

Is there any quick way to add a parameter in all methods of a package in eclipse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2009/3/16/Multifile-search-and-replace-in-Eclipse.  You will have to modify the instructions there just a tad for your needs:

Instead of telling Eclipse to search for a *literal string* you will be searching for a regular expression pattern that describes a method call/definition.  I'll leave that as an exercise for you ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If you mean to add a few parameters for one method and after that it'll be updated automatically in all packages , there is. Right click on the method and there is option Refactor -> Change Method signature, here you can add/remove parameters.

Comment: Thanks, but I was looking for something more! I think that functionality is not available.